# using a string with an if or switch for replace text

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I'm trying all the time to replace the text values in the postfields with an if condition with PHP variables. But I can't get it to work...

(the curl is inside a loop)

this works:

```
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{ 
        "fields": {
            "Mo": 31,
            "DI": 31
        }
}'
```

first try didn't work:

```
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{ 
        "fields": {
            "Mo": '.if($_POST['value'][$i] == "sunshine") {
                  31 }.',
            "Di": 31
        }
}'
```

second try didnt work:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{ 
            "fields": {
                "Mo": '.switch ($_POST['value'][$i]) {
                      case "sunshine":
                      31; }.',
                "Di": 31
            }
    }'
```

in the post value is a string named sunshine or rainy..

Comment: FYI "didn't work" is not a useful problem description, anytime. I expect this is getting you syntax errors, but all the same you should make a habit of telling us exactly what the error/failure is, not just expecting we can immediately spot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go back a step. Don't build JSON by hand, for a start - that way lies errors and syntax insanity. [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) exists for a reason.

Always make a PHP object/array as appropriate, containing the data you need, and then encode it using `json_encode`, so you always get correct JSON.

Secondly, if you need to do a conditional within a string or other assignment, and concatenate the result, use a [ternary operator](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+ternary). Either that, or do the `if` statement beforehand and then add the output into the finished variable.

For example:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    "Mo" => ($_POST['value'][$i] == "sunshine" ? 31 : null),
    "Di" => 31
);
```

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/IRWQ3

---

If you have several conditions to test for though, this can get a bit impractical.

It sounds from the description like you might need to map various string values to numeric values. In that case you don't need conditionals (if/switch/ternary) at all, you can just use an array as a lookup.

I don't know the exact requirement or data structure, but maybe something like this:

```
//lookups
$lookup = array (
    "sunshine" => 31,
    "cloudy" => 29,
    "rainy" => 27
);

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    "Mo" => $lookup[$_POST['value'][$i]],
    "Di" => 31
);
```

Comment: Hey Adyson,

thanks a lot. Your solution works when I want to check a single value. But when I try to check not only for sunshine, but also for rainy or cloudy, I can't get it to work. Therefore I had tried to solve the whole thing with a switch.

Of course you are absolutely right with the JSON. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @robsn Well what exactly did you do and what went wrong? You can nest ternary operators, although it does get a bit messy if you have more than one or two. I've edited the question to show you another possible way, though.

Comment: thanks for your help!
i just saw that i didn't add that i get the data from an option value form via $_POST. sorry :-/ 
And depending on what would be selected in the form, I would have to pass a value to the API.

sunshine = 31
rainy = 32
cloudy = 33

that's why i tried with an if or switch

Comment: Ok. Well that's why I've shown you the lookup technique...it does that for you without needing any if or switch. See my last example.

Comment: works perfectly! Thank you very much! I have only added a null => 0 at the end :-)